# Не получается указать регион в s3 github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2

Tags: golang, amazon-s3

Хочу из go сервиса подключаться к selectel для загрузки на селектел изображений.

Использую библиотеку для go https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2

```
    // Load the Shared AWS Configuration (~/.aws/config)

    cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(),
    config.WithEndpointResolver(aws.EndpointResolverFunc(
        func(service, region string) (aws.Endpoint, error) {
            return aws.Endpoint{URL: "https://s3.selcdn.ru"}, nil
        })), config.WithRegion("ru-1"), config.WithDefaultRegion("ru-1"),
    )
```

Затем еще раз явно указываю регион:

```
// Create an Amazon S3 service client

client := s3.NewFromConfig(cfg, func(options *s3.Options) {
    options.UsePathStyle = true
    options.Region = "ru-1"
})
```

Без указания пробовал так, эффект тот же:

```
// Create an Amazon S3 service client

client := s3.NewFromConfig(cfg)
```

Делаю запрос и получаю ошибку:

```
// Get the first page of results for ListObjectsV2 for a bucket

output, err := client.ListObjectsV2(context.TODO(), &s3.ListObjectsV2Input{
    Bucket: aws.String("test2"),
})
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Ошибка

```
2021/08/10 16:57:03 operation error S3: ListObjectsV2, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: <ID>, HostID: , api error AuthorizationHeaderMalformed: The authorization header is malformed; the region '' is wrong; expecting 'ru-1'
```

~/.aws/credentials и ~/.aws/config указаны:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = ***
aws_secret_access_key = ***
[default]
region = ru-1
```

Comment: S3 does not require region selection.

Comment: даже если бы поддерживал, то такого региона нет